# Python Argparse: Mutually exclusive group where one or the other are required

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to build an input list where I have two options -

```
domains.add_argument(
    '-d', dest='domain', required=True,
    help=   'Specify a target domain name'
)
```

**domain** - which would take input of a domain. And the same again, but -dL (or **domainlist**). If a domain is parsed then domainslist isn't required, *but one of them must be provided.*

I've tried to do this by adding both of these as required in a mutually exclusive group, however the error I'm presented with states that no objects in a mutually exclusive group can be required.

I could hardcode this check on startup (make neither required and handle myself) but I'm sure argparse can do it, can somebody gfive me a nudge as I haven't found this in the documentation thus far.

Comment: You really should include both options in your question (especially the part that makes them mutually exclusive) - and the full error message, too,

Comment: What syntax are you planning for `-dL` to take?

Comment: Putting a required Action in a mutually exclusive group doesn't make logical sense.  'Accept A or B but not both, but A is required?'  That's why the `add_argument` raises the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [add_mutually_exclusive_group()](https://kite.com/python/docs/argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) function according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) has required option that does exactly what you want:

> Create a mutually exclusive group. argparse will make sure that only
>   one of the arguments in the mutually exclusive group was present on
>   the command line: